# Is there a Windows Phone app or capability to handle my Google shared calendars?

Tags: 8.1, apps

I have a work account through Gmail that I have to use.

This account has

- thousands of contacts and
- [multiple](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3849/how-do-i-get-calendar-to-recognize-that-i-use-multiple-calendars-with-my-google?rq=1) [shared](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/179/how-do-i-get-other-calendars-shared-from-my-gmail-account-to-sync-to-my-window) calendars with these contacts

which I need to access frequently.

**I need to be able to find each specific contact's shared calendar.**

Is there any Windows Phone 8.1 app or functionality to handle the shared calendars and also interconnectivity between calendars and contacts? Will this be available in Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the built-in Calendar and Contacts apps would handle multiple shared google calendars and multiple google contacts.  I have my google account set up and I have multiple google calendars and a bunch of google contacts.

I don't know if you could find the contact's shared calendar, other than having them sharing their calendar with you and you adding the url for it to your calendar app.

Comment: Where would I add a URL in the calendar app...?

Comment: In google calendar click on the gear icon, go to settings.  Click on the calendars tab.  Then click on the google calendar you want to share.  Click on the ical button and that's the url to use.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work any longer (Sep 2015)

Comment: What doesn't work?  Getting the link or adding it to your Windows phone?